# How to run a method from another class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Hi I try to make my first game in ruby :)

I have two files:

```
#"game.rb" with code:
class Game
  attr_accessor :imie, :klasa, :honor
  def initialize(start_scena)
    @start = start_scena
  end

  def name()
    puts "Some text"
    exit(0)
  end
end
```

and second file

```
#"game_engine.rb"
require_relative 'game.rb'

class Start
  def initialize
    @game = Game.new(:name)
  end

  def play()
    next_scena = @start

    while true
      puts "\n---------"
      scena = method(next_scena)
      next_scena = scena.call()
    end
  end
end

go = Start.new()
go.play()
```

The question is, how can I call class Game.name method from Start.play() class. The game goes deeper, and insted of 'exit(0)' it returns :symbol of another method from "Game" class that should work.

Comment: initialize method in Start class, @game is instance of Game class, but question is what is :name there??

Comment: :name refers to method called "name" in Game calss, or it should be pointing. Im very gen at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `start` readable for the `Game` class. DO NOT call `exit(0)` in your code unless it's really necessary. Instead, use some conditions to make sure the program runs to the end of script.

```
#"game.rb" with code:
class Game
  attr_accessor :imie, :klasa, :honor
  attr_reader :start
  def initialize(start_scena)
    @start = start_scena
  end

  def name()
    puts "Some text"
    :round2
  end

  def round2
    puts "round2"
    nil
  end
end
```

Use `instance#method(...)` to get a bounded method to that instance.

```
#"game_engine.rb"
require_relative 'game.rb'

class Start
  def initialize
    @game = Game.new(:name)
  end

  def play()
    next_scene = @game.start

    while next_scene
      puts "\n---------"
      scene = @game.method(next_scene)
      next_scene = scene.call()
    end
  end
end

go = Start.new()
go.play()
```